# Why can't update my form even though my session is working php

Tags: php, forms, session

So i want a very simple update page like this example:

```
<?php  
            $sql_article = "SELECT* FROM articles WHERE article_unique_id = '".  $_SESSION['article_unique_id']."' ";
            $result_article = $conn->query($sql_article);
            if ($result_article->num_rows > 0) {
              while($row = $result_article->fetch_assoc()) 
{?>
         <form action="trry15.php" method="post">
           <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $row['title'] ?>">
         <input type="submit" name="submitUpdate" value="Submit"></form> <?php }}?>
```

and to this point code works fine session works and ect.
but when I write my update code

```
if (isset($_POST['submitUpdate'])) {
    $update_title=$_POST['title'];

    $sql_update_title = "UPDATE `articles` SET title='$update_title' WHERE article_unique_id = '".  $_SESSION['article_unique_id']."'";
    $result_update_title=$conn->query($sql_update_title);

}
```

This dosent work.
But if change `article_unique_id = '".  $_SESSION['article_unique_id']."'";` to

```
article_unique_id = '12'";
```

The code works. And I don't what is happening. I have session start function and  `$_SESSION['article_unique_id']=$_GET['article_id'];`

Comment: do you actually do $row=$result_article->fetch()?

Comment: yes, sorry i will edit it

Comment: aren't you missing 1 starting curly brace here? 
if ($result_article->num_rows > 0)

Comment: can do you var_dump($_REQUEST); and var_dump($_SESSION); and verify that data is there right before the insert query?

Comment: @Dimi this is what i get array(2) { ["status"]=> string(29) "Невалидни данни" ["article_unique_id"]=> NULL } array(2) { ["update_title"]=> string(16) "Декор за " ) ["submitUpdate"]=> string(0) "" }